# Moving parts of a SwiftUI List closer together

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-view

Is it possible to, somehow, move the text and the system image of a `Label` to be somewhat closer together?

`Label("MyString", systemImage: "wifi")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

You just need to create a custom `LabelStyle` like this…

```
struct MyLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    
    let spacing: CGFloat
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: spacing) {
            configuration.icon
            configuration.title
        }
    }
}

extension LabelStyle where Self == MyLabelStyle {
    static func mine(spacing: CGFloat) -> MyLabelStyle {
        MyLabelStyle(spacing: spacing)
    }
}
```

then use like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Label("MyString", systemImage: "wifi")
                .labelStyle(.mine(spacing: 0))
            Label("MyString", systemImage: "wifi")
                .labelStyle(.mine(spacing: 10))
            Label("MyString", systemImage: "wifi")
                .labelStyle(.mine(spacing: 20))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]